# Is there an algorithm to manually convert the two's complement of hexadecimal to decimal?

Tags: binary, hex

Let's say I have the two's complement form of the hexadecimal A41B and I want to convert it to decimal. Normally, I would convert it to binary, flip all the bits, add one, and then convert it to decimal and put the correct sign (positive or negative). Is there a faster way to do this by hand?

Comment: This is the same as converting "normal" hex to decimal, except that you have to take into account that if the most-significant digit is >= 8, then you need to subtract 2^16 from the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can:

- convert it to decimal
- subtract 2<sup>N</sup> from the result, where N is your word size (eg. for 16-bit words, subtract 65536)

In your example,

```
0xA41B = 42011
42011 - 65536 = -23525
```

Before doing the subtraction, you would check that the sign bit is in fact 1. Otherwise you would simply have a positive number.

Answer (score 3):

From [dave's corner](http://www.cypress.com/blog/daves-corner-dave-van-ess-blog/really-cool-hex-signed-interger-trick-excel):

```
=MOD(HEX2DEC(A7)+2^15,2^16)-2^15
```

for 16 bit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you for some reason don't want to or can't perform the subtraction that the other answers suggest, you can treat negative numbers like this:

1. Flip the bits
2. Add one
3. Convert to decimal as if the number were positive
4. Add a negative sign

For example: -5 is `11111011` in 8-bit 2's complement. Flipping the bits and adding one is `00000101`, which is 5 in decimal. Add negative sign and you have -5.